# Mechanical device to simulate hinge axis external/off of part

Tags: mechanical-engineering, kinematics

Take a horizontal bar 10' pinned on the right end, so that there is a hinge point on the right end. Space requirements dictate that the bar must be cut in down to 5' (cut in middle and keep the left side, discard the right side) and yet it still must pivot as it did before. To accomplish this a mechanism must be constructed underneath/around the shorter bar, but must not extend out to where the original hinge point was, as that would defeat the purpose.

This mechanism is relatively straight forward to construct out of curved track that the bar rides along, where the curved track has a radius equal to the distance from the bar to the original hinge point. **However I want to know if it's possible to construct a mechanism only out of linkages and straight track.**

I have created such a device in solidworks using only linkages and straight track that gets very close to simulating the external hinge point, but is not perfect. There is only a very small range of motion where the simulated hinge point is relatively stationary; for the rest of the motion the hinge point is not stationary at all. This leads me to believe this is not possible to construct; for the mechanism to perfectly simulate the external hinge point for a small range of motion, it must also perfectly simulate it for all range of motion. This is similar to how no two different functions, when graphed, truly overlap. If the functions perfectly overlap at all, then you know that they must be the same function. (This is not true for negative power function, which partially overlap with their positive power function counterparts. However, these functions are discontinuous, whereas the motion of linkages and track is continuous...)

Comment: This question really deserves a picture!

Comment: Here's a video: http://youtu.be/9KlqLoHQUho

The bar on the top pivots on the pin on it's right end. The bar on the bottom needs to pivot in a similar manner. I'm asking if such a mechanism exists that uses only linkages and straight track (no curved track.)